# Google Maps using custom icon for marker sometimes doesn't show up

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am getting weird and unpredictable behavior when specifying an icon to use with `google.maps.Marker`s.  Basically, the markers show up (with default icon) if I don't specify an `icon` property, but if I do specify the `icon` property, no markers show up (although I have other case where I *can* get a custom icon to show, so that's why it's weird).

Here's the relevant code:

```
              function initMap() {
                var markers = route_log.map(function(segment) {
                  return new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: new google.maps.LatLng(segment.lat, segment.lng)
                  });
                });

                ...calculate bounds..

                var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('route_log_map_map'), {
                  position: bounds.getCenter(),
                  zoom: 15
                });

                ...other unrelated code...

                for(i=0; i < markers.length; i++) {
                   markers[i].setMap(map);
                }
              }
```

This is called with:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=...key...&amp;callback=initMap" async="" defer=""></script>
```

and the above results in:

[image]

Obviously that's a lousy marker to use in this case (there's almost 2000 points), so if I change the marker creation to be like this:

```
                var markers = route_log.map(function(segment) {
                  return new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: new google.maps.LatLng(segment.lat, segment.lng),
                    icon: {
                      path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,
                      scale: 1
                    }
                  });
                });
```

the markers don't show up (and there's no errors either) (note those blue circles are unrelated to this code):

[image]

**EDIT**

This is interesting.  It works if the array I'm building the markers from has only one element, but fails to display if it has more than one.  E.g. this works and displays one marker:

```
                var route_log = [
                  {lat: 41.86219805, lng: -71.04886590000001}
                ];
                var markers = route_log.map(function(segment) {
                  return new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: new google.maps.LatLng(segment.lat, segment.lng),
                    icon: {
                      path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,
                      scale: 10
                    }
                  });
                });
```

but this displays no markers (only change is to add another element to the array):

```
                var route_log = [
                  {lat: 41.86219805, lng: -71.04886590000001},
                  {lat: 41.87219805, lng: -71.05886590000001}
                ];
                var markers = route_log.map(function(segment) {
                  return new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: new google.maps.LatLng(segment.lat, segment.lng),
                    icon: {
                      path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,
                      scale: 10
                    }
                  });
                });
```

Comment: you're scale is too small, try `scale: 10` does that show the circles? also, see this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/k2hwqzge/

Comment: `scale: 10` (or any value, in fact) has no effect; the circles still do not show up.

Comment: See the edit I just made.  Interestingly, it works when the incoming array has only one point, and fails when the array has >1 point.

Comment: seems like there is something not right in your code that you are not posting here, take a look at this fiddle which does the same thing you are doing, and works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/rvskm1zq/

Comment: @AhmedMusallam yes, I'd say your jsfiddle is exactly the same as what I'm doing (I even edited it to move map initialization later in the code and it still works).  One difference between your jsfiddle and my code is that I am calling my map initialization using a callback parameter on the maps script URL, and you're calling your initialization method directly.  I'm suspicious of that and am going to test that.

Comment: I think you will be interested in this. https://github.com/wonism/easy-map You can render map easily with it.

Comment: Curious who downvoted my question and why...

Answer (score 0):

Wow.

I have `position` in the options to the `new google.maps.Map` call.  It should be `center`, which is required.  `position` is not even a valid option for `google.maps.MapOptions`.

I blame the Google Maps API for this one. :-)